# Problem in reading the token from the URL

Tags: gwt

We are having problems reading a link which include a token. In firefox the website/program was able to recognize the token. The problem is in IE6. It cant recognize the token.
sample website is
http://www.xyz/site.html?#SPC#ABC.

Appreciate if you have any inputs to our problems.

Thanks,
MJ

Comment: What's your program - an in-browser java applet? if it's the web site itself then I don't think the # part gets passed back - that's why you'll see SO urls like /comment/1234#1234.

Comment: the website www.xyz/site.html is a java gwt application.

Answer (score 3):

assuming the actual value of the token is SPC#ABC you really need to encode the hash token, so its: SPC%23ABC - then it won't get parsed by the browser.